# How to display {object object} in a table?

Tags: json, angular, tabular, ngfor

Actually I want to display [this data](https://blockchain.info/ticker) into a table. Here, the data was {object object}. I want to display all values of "last", "buy" & "sell" from all currencies. I can do hard code, but I want to reduce the lines of code by using ng-repeat or ngFor. How to write the conditions for this?

I'm using Angular 4.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: actually i don't have any idea to iterate in this case. Because, object inside an object. If it was an array,  I can use ngFor.

Comment: you can try to convert this object to an array and then iterate it with *ngFor

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing that. Also because there are only three values, you don't really reduce your codelength by much and it is much less readable.

Comment: @Christian, I think you didn't understood my question. BTW, i got few answers and now studying about it. see the plnkr example in below answer. That's what exactly i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the replies guys, your ways were working fine. But i found more easier way to do this:

```
function generateArray(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map((key) =>  obj[key] );
}
```

this will convert the json object to array and

```
<tr *ngFor="let post of posts">
            <td>{{post.last}}</td>
            <td>{{post.buy}}</td>
            <td>{{post.sell}}</td>  
          </tr>
```

this will iterate the json into a table.

P.S: I've saved the json into "posts" called "obj" from "posts".

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a pipe and then you can iterate through object.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'ObjNgFor',  pure: false })
export class ObjNgFor implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args: any[] = null): any {
        return Object.keys(value)//.map(key => value[key]);
    }
}
```

This plnkr might help you.

[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/9amL4aUYX086WrtjmPtu?p=preview)

Comment: I woudln't use pure:false. That way after every valuechange the pipe gets executed again.

Answer (score 0):

ngFor works on iterables, thus in your case you need to first transform the json data into an array.

```
let blockChainData:any = { ... } //data.retrieved.from.server;
let blockChainDataArray:Array<any> = [];

let dataKeys:Array<string> = Object.keys(blockChainData);
dataKeys.forEach((key:string) => {
   let entry:any = blockChainData[key]; // Retrieve the object associated with the currency
   entry.originalCurrency = key; // Preserve the original currency
   blockChainDataArray.push(entry);
});
```

In your html code, iterate over the array

```
<td *ngFor="let entry of blockChainDataArray">{{ entry.originalCurrency }} {{ entry.buy }} {{ entry.sell }} {{ entry.last }} </td>
```